# Creating a grid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, prism-4

I've a table in a database where I need to show all the rows's content (as a TextBlock) and to the right of each TextBlock I need to show a TextBox so the user can enter a value (a number) for each row and also I need to be able to change the color of any TextBox when the value provided by the user is negative.

Can someone give me a clue with this?

PD: I'm using WPF with Prism 4 and MVVM pattern and VS2010 Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you a complete solution, but I can point you in the right direction.

I start by creating a data structure that contains properties for `Name` and `Value`, and that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for Property Change notification.

Next in the `ViewModel` (or possibly `Model`), I would make would be an `ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>`, and populate it with the data from the database.

In the XAML, I would use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) bound to the collection, and overwrite the `ItemTemplate` to render each item as either a Horizontal `StackPanel` or a `Grid`, containing the `Label` and `TextBox`

For the `TextBox.Foreground` property, I would bind it to the same value that `TextBox.Text` is bound to, except I'd also use a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) in the binding which checks to see if the value is above or below 0, and returns the correct color. Since it is a binding, it will automatically update whenever the value changes.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"
         Foreground="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource MyCustomConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you guys I'll try first with the @Rachel's proposition and later I'll try with the Validator.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be nice to know what you've tried so we can help you better, but you almost certainly want to be binding your data to a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) or, if you absolutely need more flexibility (so far it doesn't sound like that's the case), an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol). You don't want to be just creating a `Grid` dynamically.

Your question about the TextBox and how to change it's color when the value is negative is actually a separate question from how to do your layout. I'd look into the [`Validation`](http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html) components of WPF for that.